# Is it possible to share GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS between sub projects in Workspace of Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to share GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS between sub projects in Workspace, Suppose i have a workspace which has a Project ABC, Project XYZ, Project IJK We can add GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS in build settings for each project is there any way to share a MACRO between all projects of workspace. Is there any better solution to achieve this using XCConfig files etc.